# OpenVPN server on Kubernetes cluster / DNS and Service resolution

Tags: dns, openvpn, kubernetes

I have a **Kubernetes** cluster running *applications* (currently on a set of Vagrant CoreOS VMs on a local server)

I want to be able to debug a particular application locally on my laptop, so I worked on setting up VPN into the cluster: a **client/server VPN** based on `kylemanna/docker-openvpn`, deployed as a regular **Pod**

I created the cert/key pairs, client certs etc...
I can connect to the VPN fine.

Now, connecting to the VPN server doesn't get me much if I can't access the Services.
I have the DNS addon running skyDNS in the cluster. I can `nslookup` my services from other pods in the cluster, so all that works fine, but I can't resolve Services by name on the VPN client.
I can ping Pods by IP from the VPN client (in the subnet `10.2.0.0/16`) but I can't resolve with DNS

a `nslookup` from the client returns:

```
nslookup myservice 10.3.0.10
Server:     10.3.0.10
Address:    10.3.0.10#53

** server can't find myservice: SERVFAIL
```

One of the problems of troubleshooting is that neither `ping` nor `traceroute` work on the DNS IP (from any pod), yet it resolves services, so `nslookup` is the way I know to check, but that is not very informative.

The VPN host IP the Pod binds to is `192.168.10.152`
The Kubernetes subnet is `10.2.0.0/16`
The SkyDNS server is at `10.3.0.10`

The VPN server subnet is `10.8.0.0/24`
On the VPN server ifconfig gives:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0A:02:16:45
          inet addr:10.2.22.69  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
```

So `10.2.22.69` is the **Pod** IP and the VPN Server IP is `10.8.0.1` with the Gateway being `10.8.0.2` i guess.

On the VPN server pod the routign table looks like:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.2.22.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.2.22.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.254.0   10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

I can reach my applications by IP (and get data) but couldn't when using the service IP (the proxy IP which is on the 10.3.0.0 subnet)

I added the route `route add -net 10.3.0.0/16 gw 10.8.0.2` to the VPN Server and I can then use the Service IP to get data but the `nslookup` just times out then.

I guess the traffic may not be coming back from the DNS.  DNS is itself a proxied service in Kubernetes, so that adds a level of complexity.
Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally my config looks like this:

```
docker run -v /etc/openvpn:/etc/openvpn --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_genconfig \
-u udp://192.168.10.152:1194 \
-n 10.3.0.10 \
-n 192.168.10.1 \
-n 8.8.8.8 \
-n 75.75.75.75 \
-n 75.75.75.76 \
-s 10.8.0.0/24 \
-N \
-p "route 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0" \
-p "route 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH cluster.local" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH svc.cluster.local" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH default.svc.cluster.local"
```

`-u` for the VPN server address and port

`-n` for all the DNS servers to use

`-s` to define the VPN subnet (as it defaults to 10.2.0.0 which is used by Kubernetes already)

`-d` to disable NAT

`-p` to push options to the client

`-N` to enable NAT: it seems critical for this setup on Kubernetes

the last part, pushing the search domains to the client, was the key to getting `nslookup` etc.. to work.

note that curl didn't work at first, but seems to start working after a few seconds. So it does work but it takes a bit of time for curl to be able to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue a year ago and decided to make something specific for kubernetes: https://github.com/pieterlange/kube-openvpn

(based on kylemanna's openvpn docker image)

Comment: Could you please add some additional information about it here, e.g. in case the link stops working.